# Why does this identity in these abstract derivatives hold true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, binomial-coefficients

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.11949), the authors claim the following to be true:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{l}\binom{m}{l_1,...,l_n}\partial^{m-l_i}D_{a_j-l_j}=D_{a_j}\partial^m,
\end{equation}
where $D_a$ is the partial derivative (defined in the usual way) in an abstract variable $Z_a$, for $a\in\mathbb{N}^2$, $\partial^k := \sum_{a\in\mathbb{N}^2}Z_{a+k}D_a$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}^2$, $m\in\mathbb{N}^2$, $l=(l_1,l_2,...,l_n)\in(\mathbb{N}^2)^n$ and
$$\binom{m}{l_1,...,l_n}:= \frac{m!}{l_1!\cdots l_n!}.$$
They claim that this relationship is elementary but I have not been able to prove it to myself. Any help in understanding this will be greatly appreciated!

P.S. They argue in greater generality, for example $m\in\mathbb{N}^{d+1}$ and $a$ are *typed* in the sense that $a\in\mathfrak{L}^+\times\mathbb{N}^{d+1}$, but for my own purpose $\mathfrak{L}^+$ is a singleton and $m\in\mathbb{N}^2$, which is why I have presented it in this manner above.

Edit: Fixed a typo in the original identity, as pointed out by Darij in their comment.

Comment: What does $l_1!$ mean if $l_1 \in \mathbb{N}^2$?

Comment: Also, how can there be an $l_j$ on the right hand side if the $l_j$ is a summation variable on the left hand side?

Comment: In the context of multi-indices, for $\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_d)\in\mathbb{N}^d$, $\alpha!:=\alpha_1!\cdots\alpha_d!$. As for your second comment, you are correct that is a typo, edited now.